# Optimal Calibration for a Test Set

Tags: statistical-inference, bayesian, system-identification

I want to calibrate the parameters $\theta$ of a known forward model $y=f(\theta, x)$, i.e., I want to identify offsets of around +- 10% from a nominal model $\theta_0$

I can not measure $y$ directly, but my measurement function $h_c$ only depends on this forward model:
$y_c = h_c(f(\theta, x))$
Let's call the calibration set $C$, consisting of $N_C$ pairs $(y_c, x_c)$.

When I identify the $\theta$ via a MAP approach or some variant of Least Squares, I minimize the error in $h_c$ over $C$.
But I want to achieve something else.

Instead, I want to minimize the error of a test function $y_t = h_t(\theta, x)$ over a set $T$ of pairs $(y_t, x_t)$.
However, my measurement setup does not allow me to collect measurements for this directly.

To summarize, I have to measure functions.
For $h_c$, I can collect measurements $C$ and perform the calibration.
But I care about minimizing the error of $h_t$ over $T$.
All the functions and sets are known.
However, they do not model the real system perfectly and there are epistemic errors.

Are there any strategies for this kind of scenario?
I am also looking for literature on this topic.